# Nginx: enable/disable caching depending on HTTP method

Tags: nginx

I asked this question on serverfault, but nobody answered. Hope, stackoverflow people know Nginx better :)

I want to handle all [GET] requests to /api from cache and handle all other requests as in last location block (without cache). All the requests to /api with methods PUT, POST, DELETE also have not to use cache.

I saw the similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/152745/nginx-proxy-by-request-method), but still can not understand how to use it in my case.

Thanks in advance.

My config:

```
location / {
    root /var/www/project/web;
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}


location ~ ^/api {
    root /var/www/project/web/app.php;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/?.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_cache fcgi;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 5m;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

}

location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    root /var/www/project/web;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/?.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's pretty simple thankfully. Nginx's modules (proxy, fastcgi, uwsgi etc) all have the ability to inform a request not to use the cache.

```
location ~ ^/api {
    root /var/www/project/web/app.php;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/?.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    # Don't cache anything by default
    set $no_cache 1;

    # Cache GET requests
    if ($request_method = GET)
    {
        set $no_cache 0;
    }

    fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;

    fastcgi_cache fcgi;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 5m;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

As per Richard Smith's suggestion, a more elegant solution using the maps directive is below:

```
map $request_method $api_cache_bypass {
    default       1;
    GET           0;
}

location ~ ^/api {
    root /var/www/project/web/app.php;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/?.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_cache_bypass $api_cache_bypass;
    fastcgi_no_cache $api_cache_bypass;

    fastcgi_cache fcgi;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 5m;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

The additions to the location are essentially telling Nginx to use or ignore the cache depending on the verb. It sets $no_cache to 1, which will bypass the cache for all requests, except where the method is GET when it is set to 0 which instructs it to use the cache (if available).

Comment: Have you considered using map instead of the set/if/set method?

Comment: No to be fair, but only because I didn't know it existed. So thanks for that. I know if's are generally frowned upon by the core team due to performance, does this equate to the the map directive as well?

Comment: Ifs can also have unexpected side-effects - but regarding performance - I really don't know. But the map solution does look more elegant :-)

Comment: Yeah thats fair. My only concern with it would be as its only available at the http context, it might get a bit confusing, would have to reuse variable names if a different location had different caching requirements (however unlikely that would be). I'll throw in a maps option too as I do like it

Comment: I only explicitly defined the verbs so that if they needed/wanted them to be changed it would have been easier to...but it would appear you're all about that elegance ;)

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your answers! :)

Comment: Old question: but I think the main reason to avoid `if`s is that they don't act the way you may expect them to (performance is not the concern). The comment about the map being confusing because it's in the http context is backwards IMO: that is actually far _less_ likely to lead to confusion since it's a more direct definition of how a variable should be derived for a given request. The specific approach of setting a value in an `if` such as above is particularly fragile depending on what other modules are in play. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/